# DataGridView how to have WrapMode = true (multiline cells) and autoadjust width properly?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Apparently, the only way to have multiline cells in a `DataGridView` is by setting the `WrapMode` of its `DefaultCellStyle` to `true`. My problem is that I also want the width of the column to adjust automatically to the content of the cell, instead of wrapping it by adding line breaks.

Even if I set `AutoSizeColumnsMode` to `AllCells`, it will wrap the text instead of making the header bigger. I would also like the row height to adjust automatically. So I don't really want to wrap anything at all. Just adjust width and height to the size of the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode` property to `DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.DATAGRIDVIEW.COLUMNHEADERSHEIGHTSIZEMODE%29;k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.DATAGRIDVIEW%29;k%28VS.PROPERTIES%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true)'s more info;